# tsql DATEDIFF call in minutes without rounding off seconds

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime, datediff

I am making a DATEDIFF() call in SQL server 2008 as part of a stored procedure, which potentially is returning values of as small as 3 seconds or less. I would like the format to be in MM:SS (i.e. 00:03 when 3 seconds). I was originally using the call in minutes:

`DATEDIFF(mi, SELECT MAX(startDate) FROM myTable , SELECT MAX(EndDate) FROM myTable)`

However, this was rounding down to the nearest minute, and thus erasing the seconds values. How can I achieve a format as specified above using DATEDIFF?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To the nearest second:

```
DATEDIFF(ss, SELECT MAX(startDate) FROM myTable, SELECT MAX(EndDate) FROM myTable)
```

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Note: `DATEDIFF` won't give you a 'format'. It just returns an integer. So you'll need to cast/format appropriately.

I suspect the closest you will get easily is using `CAST` with format `108`:

```
select convert(char(8), dateadd(ss, DATEDIFF(ss, SELECT MAX(startDate) FROM myTable, 
                                                 SELECT MAX(EndDate) FROM myTable)), 
               cast(0 as DateTime)) , 108)
```

e.g.

```
select convert(char(8), dateadd(ss, DATEDIFF(ss, '2012-12-16 12:00:00', 
                                                 '2012-12-16 12:13:09'), 
                                cast(0 as DateTime)), 108)
```

returns:

> ```
> 00:13:09
> ```

[Note: If you want to round to the nearest 3 seconds, you could modify this: [TSQL: Round to Nearest 15 Minute Interval](http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com.au/2011/02/tsql-round-to-nearest-15-minute.html) ]